# How to add a number to elements of a numpy array but not all elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, element

This is what I'm trying to do:
I have a 2D numpy array:

```
A = [[   0,    0,  400,  400],
     [   0,  400,  400,  800],
     [   0,  800,  400, 1010],
     [ 400,    0,  800,  400],
     [ 400,  400,  800,  800],
     [ 400,  800,  800, 1010],
     [ 800,    0,  910,  400],
     [ 800,  400,  910,  800],
     [ 800,  800,  910, 1010]]
```

I want to add +20 to all the non-zeros elements of the 1st column. So, the answer should look like this:

```
A =[[   0,    0,  400,  400],
    [   0,  420,  400,  800],
    [   0,  820,  400, 1010],
    [ 400,    0,  800,  400],
    [ 400,  420,  800,  800],
    [ 400,  820,  800, 1010],
    [ 800,    0,  910,  400],
    [ 800,  420,  910,  800],
    [ 800,  820,  910, 1010]]
```

It is possible with loops, but isn't there a vectorized method, or something within the numpy library to implement this?

All I can think of is:

```
A[:,1] = A[:,1][A[:,1] != 0] + 20
```

but it doesn't work the way I want it to because it only returns a decremented array with only the modified non-zero values, hence it gives an error.

Comment: I tried this, but it adds 20 to all non-zero elements, and not just the 1st column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short version is

```
A[A[:,1]!=0,1] += 20
```

That means add 20 to all rows in the first column, where the first column is not zero.

More general

```
A[A[:, i]!=k,j] += l
```

Add l to all rows in the j-th column, where the rows in the i-th column are not k.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
A[:,1] = np.where(A[:,1]!=0, A[:,1]+20, 0)
print(A)
```

Prints:

```
[[   0    0  400  400]
 [   0  420  400  800]
 [   0  820  400 1010]
 [ 400    0  800  400]
 [ 400  420  800  800]
 [ 400  820  800 1010]
 [ 800    0  910  400]
 [ 800  420  910  800]
 [ 800  820  910 1010]]
```

Comment: While this is a good use of where, it just makes me wonder why the function is so popular to begin with

Answer (score -1):

Use the numpy Function [apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
def addTwenty(x):
  if(x[1] > 0):
    x[1] += 20
  return x
A = np.apply_along_axis(addTwenty, 1, A)
```

Prints:

```
array([[   0,    0,  400,  400],
       [   0,  420,  400,  800],
       [   0,  820,  400, 1010],
       [ 400,    0,  800,  400],
       [ 400,  420,  800,  800],
       [ 400,  820,  800, 1010],
       [ 800,    0,  910,  400],
       [ 800,  420,  910,  800],
       [ 800,  820,  910, 1010]])
```

Comment: This is a python level loop under the hood, technically not what OP wants